# Calculating the 3-norm of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the 3-norm of the matrix y here but I keep getting an error that says

```
ValueError: Invalid norm order for matrices.
```

This is the code that I tried

```
    y = np.random.rand(5,1)
    print(y)
    p = 3
    ly = npla.norm(y,p)
    print('ly =',ly,)
```

I'm not sure how to go about calculating the 3-norm here so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try adding `axis=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `axis=0` in the `norm` method since you have a 5x1 matrix and you want to calculate the norm over column 1.

If you would have just a python list, it would be okay without.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [norm documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) the standard inputs does not include order=3.

As stated in the post previous you need to add an axis parameter where x=0.

try:

```
np.linalg.norm(yourMatrix,3,axis=0)
```